# Error: OAuthException code 1 during test user creation

Tags: testing, facebook-test-users

Since 1 week max, i got this error when i try to create a test user.

https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/accounts/test-users?installed=false&name=profilname&locale=en_US&permissions=read_stream&method=post&access_token=APP_TOKEN

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 1
   }
}
```

Authentication application type is WEB.
My other apps don't have this problem!

Comment: It would be good if you'd add some additional brief information and provide more details about your issue.

Comment: You didn't by any chance reached 500 test users already, have you?

Comment: I'm getting this issue as well, but it seems random. I have no idea what triggers it. I'm trying to create a user with installed=false